# Using python gdal.BuildVRTOptions()

Tags: python, nodata, gdalbuildvrt

I want to define no data values when working with gdal.BuildVRT(). According to the gdal.documentation http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html, by creating a gdal.BuildVRTOptions (srcNodata=-99, VRTNodata=-99), I should be able force the gdal.BuiltVRT() to incorporate nodata values.

Yet, doing so as one can be seen below, does not work.

```
gdal.BuildVRT(file_open,None,srs_wkt,gdal.GRA_Bilinear,gdal.BuildVRTOptions (srcNodata=-99, VRTNodata=-99))
```

and I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/esaiet/Dropbox/Python_programing/Python_scripts/converting_porjection_vrt_II.py", line 45, in <module>
    vrt_ds=gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(file_open,None,srs_wkt,gdal.GRA_Bilinear,gdal.BuildVRTOptions(srcNodata=None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/GDAL-2.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/gdal.py", line 2872, in AutoCreateWarpedVRT
    return _gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(*args)
TypeError: in method 'AutoCreateWarpedVRT', argument 5 of type 'double'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Your arguments are incorrect, you have all positional args. There are only 2 positional args `destName, srcDSOrSrcDSTab` and the rest are keyword args, either ALL `keyword=arg`  OR `options=gdal.BuildVRTOptions()` (possbly also a mix of keyword args and options="keyword=string" or ["a=list", "of=strings"] but not sure).

From [the docs](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#BuildVRT):

```
BuildVRT(destName, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs)
source code 
Build a VRT from a list of datasets.
Arguments are :
  destName --- Output dataset name
  srcDSOrSrcDSTab --- an array of Dataset objects or filenames, or a Dataset object or a filename
Keyword arguments are :
  options --- return of gdal.InfoOptions(), string or array of strings
  other keywords arguments of gdal.BuildVRTOptions()
If options is provided as a gdal.BuildVRTOptions() object, other keywords are ignored.
```

Try:

```
output_vrt = "" # empty string OR None OR /vsimem/in_memory.vrt OR /path/to/file.vrt
gdal.BuildVRT(output_vrt, file_open, options=gdal.BuildVRTOptions(outputSRS=srs_wkt, resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Bilinear, srcNodata=-99, VRTNodata=-99))
```

Comment: Do you know the correct syntax for the `-tr` (target resolution) option? I have tried `options=gdal.BuildVRTOptions("tr='5 5'")`, but whatever I set, the '5 5' is not applied

Comment: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#BuildVRTOptions `xRes=5, yRes=5`